# Trouble employing BeanItemContainer and TreeTable in Vaadin

Tags: javabeans, vaadin, treetable

I have reviewed multiple examples for how to construct a `TreeTable` from from a `Container` datasource and just adding items iterating over an `Object[][]`.  Still I'm stuck for my use case.

I have a bean like so...

```
public class DSRUpdateHourlyDTO implements UniquelyKeyed<AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId>, Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId id = new AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId();

private String commitStatus;
private BigDecimal economicMax;
private BigDecimal economicMin;

public void setCommitStatus(String commitStatus) { this.commitStatus = commitStatus; }
public void setEconomicMax(BigDecimal economicMax) { this.economicMax = economicMax; }
public void setEconomicMin(BigDecimal economicMin) { this.economicMin = economicMin; }

public String getCommitStatus() { return commitStatus; }
public BigDecimal getEconomicMax() { return economicMax; }
public BigDecimal getEconomicMin() { return economicMin; }
public AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId getId() { return id; }

@Override
public AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId getKey() {
    return getId();
}

}
```

The `AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId` is a compound id.  It looks like...

```
public class AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId implements Serializable, AssetOwned, HasHour, Locatable,
UniquelyKeyed<AssetOwnedHourlyLocatableId> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String location;

private String hour;

private String assetOwner;

@Override
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

@Override
public void setLocation(final String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

@Override
public String getHour() {
    return hour;
}

@Override
public void setHour(final String hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

@Override
public String getAssetOwner() {
    return assetOwner;
}

@Override
public void setAssetOwner(final String assetOwner) {
    this.assetOwner = assetOwner;
}

}
```

I want to generate a grid where the `hour`s are pivoted into column headers and the `location` is the only other additional column header.

E.g.,

```
Location    1   2   3   4   5   6   ...   24
```

would be the column headers.

Underneath each column you might see...

```
> L1 
  > Commit Status    Status1 .... Status24
  > Eco Min          EcoMin1 .... EcoMin24
  > Eco Max          EcoMax1 .... EcoMax24
> L2
  > Commit Status    Status1 .... Status24
  > Eco Min          EcoMin1 .... EcoMin24
  > Eco Max          EcoMax1 .... EcoMax24
```

So, if I'm provided a `List<DSRUpdateHourlyDTO>` I want to convert it into the presentation format described above.

What would be the best way to do this?

I have a few additional functional requirements.

- I want to be able to toggle between read-only and editable views of the same table.
- I want to be able to complete a round-trip to a datasource (e.g., JPAContainerSource).
- I (will eventually) want to filter items by any part of the compound id.

My challenge is in the adaptation.  I well understand the simple use case where I could take the list and simply splat it into a `BeanItemContainer` and use `addNestedContainerProperty` and `setVisibleColumns`.  Pivoting properties into columns seems to be what's stumping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was an ill-conceived question.

For data entry purposes, one could use a `BeanItemContainer` and have the columns include nested container property `hour` from the composite `id` and instead of a `TreeTable`, use a `Table` that has `commitStatus`, `ecoMin` and `ecoMax` as columns.  Limitation: you'd only ever query for / submit one `assetOwner` and `location`'s worth of data.

As for display, where you don't care to filter one `assetOwner` and `location`'s worth of data, you could pivot the `hour` info as originally described.  You could just convert the original bean into another bean suitable for display (where each hour is its own column).